# Handling character entities in Java using JDOM : how to?

Tags: java, xml, entities

I've to convert a xml file to a sgml file.

I'm using Java 1.6.0.31. and jDOM 2.0.5

I do not own the sgml's DTD.
The DTDs declare lots of character entities ( like &gamma; , &omega;... but i'm not allowed to use the &#947; entity form)

I do own the xml ( I mean I'm able to edit the xsd and do whatever I want with this part)
The XML's xsd do not declare these entities, but I'm using a xml editor that allow inserting these entities

My problem is when I try to convert a xml containing these entitites I get a "&entities; referenced but not declared" exception message.

The code is :

```
    File sourceFile = new File(path);
    if (sourceFile.exists()) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        factory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
        factory.setValidating(false);
        factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
        factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(false);
        DOMBuilder builder = new DOMBuilder();

        this.xmlDocument = builder.build(factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(sourceFile));
```

The factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse() is the exception thrower (Obviously).

I've been looking for answers, but I'm not good enough with JDOM to decide what I should do, so my question is : What is the safest thing to do to allow entities resolve in this case ?

Should I create a custom EntityResolver that will do the job ?
Should I force the inputed xml to have &#947; format entities then replace the numeric value by "full-text" value ?

Thanks for your help !

EDIT: Replacing & so you can see the code, not the entities :/

Answer (score 0):

Jeez again,

I've ended doing something very ugly : 
I've inserted all the ENTITIES I needed in the document internal subset using a `filecontent.replaceFirst("<!DOCTYPE X \\[", "<!DOCTYPE X [" + getEntityFile());`

and

```
function getEntityFile() {
return FileUtils.readFileToString(f);
}
```

where f is the DTD file containing all the char entities I'am allowed to use ( copied from the SGML DTD).. So I can avoid the "entites referenced but not declared". Then these entities were replaced ( Yeah, I haven't found a way to not replace **internal** entities using jDOM2 => If someone have an idea, I'll bring the beer)

And at the end, when I'm outputing the SGML file, I replace the value by there entities reference ...

I'm ashamed, but for now, it work ...